# Understanding ～の方を回っていく

Tags: grammar

The speaker has just decided what route to drive:

> 「よし、次の交差点を渡ったら、右折して**路地の方を回っていきましょう**」
>   Right! When I cross the next junction I'll turn right and ???

I don't understand the part in bold. Literally, I have something like:

> I will keep turning through the direction of the lane.　or,
>   I will turn through the direction of the lane and go.

I can't understand what 'turn through a direction' 方を回る means.
I'm also not sure what the function of いく is here. Hence my two alternatives.

Comment: http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/210283/meaning/m0u/ ３ 順々に決まった場所などをめぐる to visit places in a route in order. ５ 寄り道をする to drop in. (It's not appropriate to translate …ていく into "keep ...ing")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't feel the previous answers are correct. 回っていきましょう is used to generally refer to an act of deliberately avoiding the shortest path, usually to arrive faster etc (e.g. there is a traffic jam on the shortest path so you go through the ally). It doesn't refer to any actual, physical change in bearing. For example in the sentence you've given, you arrive immediately into the 路地 by doing 右折. You don't make any additional turns.

You can see this in expressions like 急がば回れ. It just generally refers to the act of "going around" rather than literary turning to any direction.

So I would translate it as:

> Right, once we cross the next junction, let's turn right and go through the alley (rather than the main road)

Answer (score 0):

To complement the other answer, according to [this online japanese thesaurus](http://thesaurus.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%BE%E3%82%8F%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%81%8F), 回っていく can also have a meaning similar to "to advance smoothly" and "things progressing as well as/the way it was intended", which is a bit less literal than in that context.

Comment: I think you mean the other "left".  右=みぎ.  That is, "right"

Comment: @A.Ellett thanks for pointing that out, I edited it!

Comment: Same here, -1 because I think the translation is wrong (see my answer) (sorry)

Comment: @EnnoShioji thanks for pointing it out, I learned something new ^^ I'll edit to add some meanings that I found in an online dictionary to complement your answer!

Comment: I see... That meaning is quite a bit different though. It comes from turning wheels (whereas the diversion comes from how you draw a part of a circle by going around something)

Answer (score -1):

You've got the translation down almost.

I'd go with

> OK, once you've crossed at the next intersection, turn right and head in the direction of the alley.

方を回っていく means to "go off in the direction of..."

Comment: -1 because I think the translation is wrong (see my answer)

Comment: @EnnoShioji if you dislike that i didn't use the volitional form in the translation that's because i feel in English it would sound a tad strange. if it's something else you're objecting to then i'm interested in what it is.

Comment: Yeah.. it's something else.. Maybe you could think of the 回る as [迂回]{うかい}する(make a detour)

Comment: omg. i totally misread that character as "mukatte". argh. how embarrassing. thanks for the clarification.